# Gracefully disconnect a WebSocket connection with Celluloid

Tags: ruby, websocket, google-chrome-devtools, eventmachine, celluloid

### Situation

I connect to a WebSocket with Chrome's [Remote Debugging Protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol), using a Rails application and a class that implements Celluloid, or more specifically, [`celluloid-websocket-client`](https://github.com/jeremyd/celluloid-websocket-client).

The problem is that I don't know how to disconnect the WebSocket cleanly.

When an error happens inside the actor, but the main program runs, Chrome somehow still makes the WebSocket unavailable, not allowing me to attach again.

### Code Example

Here's the code, completely self-contained:

```
require 'celluloid/websocket/client'

class MeasurementConnection

  include Celluloid

  def initialize(url)
    @ws_client = Celluloid::WebSocket::Client.new url, Celluloid::Actor.current
  end

  # When WebSocket is opened, register callbacks
  def on_open
    puts "Websocket connection opened"
    # @ws_client.close to close it
  end

  # When raw WebSocket message is received
  def on_message(msg)
    puts "Received message: #{msg}"
  end

  # Send a raw WebSocket message
  def send_chrome_message(msg)
    @ws_client.text JSON.dump msg
  end

  # When WebSocket is closed
  def on_close(code, reason)
    puts "WebSocket connection closed: #{code.inspect}, #{reason.inspect}"
  end

end

MeasurementConnection.new ARGV[0].strip.gsub("\"","")
while true
  sleep
end
```

### What I've tried

- When I uncomment `@ws_client.close`, I get:

  ```
  NoMethodError: undefined method `close' for #<Celluloid::CellProxy(Celluloid::WebSocket::Client::Connection:0x3f954f44edf4)
  ```

  But I thought [this was delegated](https://github.com/jeremyd/celluloid-websocket-client/blob/master/lib/celluloid/websocket/client/connection.rb#L40)? At least the `.text` method works too?
- When I call `terminate` instead (to quit the Actor), the WebSocket is still opened in the background.
- When I call `terminate` on the `MeasurementConnection` object that I create in the main code, it makes the Actor appear dead, but still does not free the connection.

### How to reproduce

You can test this yourself by starting Chrome with `--remote-debugging-port=9222` as command-line argument, then checking `curl http://localhost:9222/json` and using the `webSocketDebuggerUrl` from there, e.g.:

```
ruby chrome-test.rb $(curl http://localhost:9222/json 2>/dev/null | grep webSocket | cut -d ":" -f2-)
```

If no `webSocketDebuggerUrl` is available, then something is still connecting to it.

It used to work when I was using `EventMachine` similar to [this example](https://www.igvita.com/2012/04/09/driving-google-chrome-via-websocket-api/), but not with `faye/websocket-client`, but [`em-websocket-client`](https://github.com/mwylde/em-websocket-client) instead. Here, upon stopping the EM loop (with `EM.stop`), the WebSocket would become available again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I used the 0.0.1 version of the `celluloid-websocket-client` gem which did not delegate the `close` method.

Using 0.0.2 worked, and the code would look like this:

In `MeasurementConnection`:

```
def close
  @ws_client.close
end
```

In the main code:

```
m = MeasurementConnection.new ARGV[0].strip.gsub("\"","")
m.close
while m.alive?
  m.terminate
  sleep(0.01)
end
```

Comment: I've just tried to use the code, and I don't get "Websocket connection opened:" output along with other callbacks. Could the problem lie in that I use WEBrick?

Comment: My code example doesn't require a server. I run my actual production app using Unicorn, so I'm not sure about WEBrich. But then again, I don't think it would change anything?

Comment: You are right. I discovered on_close callback is fine, but on_open and on_mesage are not. It works fine with em_websocket though

Comment: The issue was with SSL. I pushed pull request to repository

Comment: @IlyaCherevkov Interesting, thanks for the info. The maintainer of the repository isn't that active, so I hope it gets merged soon.